# Grid Search keeps running wit asterisk (*) and never concludes, without any output

Tags: python, parameters, cross-validation, grid-search

Code keeps running (*) without end. Once completed will pass values and retest the models (Logistics, SVM and Forest) using the optimal parameters from gridsearch

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

param_range = [0.0001, 0.001, .005, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0]
classifiers = [
               {"clf":LogisticRegression(random_state=0), "param_grid":[{'C': ``param_range}]}, 
              #{"clf":KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5), "param_grid":[{'n_neighbors': param_range}]},
              #{"clf": MLPClassifier(), "param_grid":[{'C': param_range}]},
               {"clf":SVC(random_state=0), "param_grid":[{'C': param_range, 'gamma': param_range, 'kernel': ['linear','rbf']}]}, 
               {"clf":RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0), "param_grid":[{'max_depth': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, None], 
                                                                             'max_features': [None, 'auto'],
                                                                            'n_estimators': [10, 100, 1000]}]}
              ]


model_scores = []
for classifier in classifiers:
    # Inner Cross Validation, searches for the best parameters
    gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=classifier["clf"], param_grid=classifier["param_grid"], scoring='accuracy', cv=3)
    # Outer Cross Validation, evaluates the model
    model_scores.append(cross_val_score(gs, X_train_std, y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=10))

models_df = pd.DataFrame(model_scores, columns=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                         index=["LR", "SVM", "Forest"])
models_df["Mean"] = models_df.mean(axis=1)
models_df
```

Comment: need more explanation

Comment: After running code above i will pass the values to the models plugging the optimal values from above back into the model and print updated scores for my train and test data:
# Grid Search (Logistic Regression) comparing Test with Training set accuracy

gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=log_reg, param_grid=[{'C': param_range}], scoring='accuracy', cv=3)
gs.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
train_score = gs.score(X_train_std, y_train)
test_score = gs.score(X_test_std, y_test)
print("Train score: {} \nTest score: {}".format(train_score, test_score))